# how to get all value on using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $originalDate = $row['date'];
  $newDate = date("F/d/y", strtotime($originalDate)); ?>
  <script>
      var name = '<?= $row['name'] ?>';
      var description = '<?= $row['description'] ?>';
      var type = '<?= $row['type'] ?>';
      var json_event = [{
        id: "bHay68s", // Event's ID (required)
        name: "<?= $row['name'] ?>", // Event name (required)
        date: "<?= $newDate ?>", // Event date (required)
        type: "<?= $row['type'] ?>", // Event type (required)
        description: "<?= $row['description'] ?>",
        everyYear: true // Same event every year (optional)
      },{
        name: "Vacation Leave",
        badge: "02/13 - 02/15", // Event badge (optional)
        date: ["February/13/2022", "February/15/2022"], // Date range
        description: "Vacation leave for 3 days.", // Event description (optional)
        type: "event",
        color: "#63d867" // Event custom color (optional)
      }];
      $("#evoCalendar").evoCalendar({
        calendarEvents: json_event
      });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

This function I'll get only 1 row. I need all value like

```js
{
  name: "Vacation Leave",
  badge: "02/13 - 02/15", // Event badge (optional)
  date: ["February/13/2022", "February/15/2022"], // Date range
  description: "Vacation leave for 3 days.", // Event description (optional)
  type: "event",
  color: "#63d867" // Event custom color (optional)
}, {
  name: "Vacation Leave",
  badge: "03/13 - 03/15", // Event badge (optional)
  date: ["march/13/2022", "march/15/2022"], // Date range
  description: "Vacation leave for 3 days.", // Event description (optional)
  type: "event",
  color: "#63d867" // Event custom color (optional)
}
```

database

| Sl.no | Name | Date | Type | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | test | 01/02/2022 | event1 | calendar test |
| 02 | test2 | 01/02/2022 | event2 | calendar test2 |
| 03 | test3 | 01/03/2022 | event1 | calendar test |

I want Get all Value. Please Help

Comment: You are creating the same JavaScript variable assignments multiple times in a loop, all in the same scope - so they will of course overwrite each other.

Comment: Try to store your json_events in an array and after that initiate the `$("#evoCalendar")` only once. (outside of your `$result->fetch_assoc()` while loop)